# How to keep pivot table from expanding into occupied rows and columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with other calculations surrounding it. My issue is that if more row/column groupings are added to the pivot table, it extends and reaches the cells where these other calculations are, and eventually must delete their contents if I wish to keep on making the pivot table "bigger". Is there a way to border a pivot table with say 2 empty rows and columns around it, so that even if I want to make the pivot table bigger, there still exists a border between it and my calculations?

Comment: You can manually add the rows and columns, but the Pivot Table will not respect the "boundaries" you have created for it.  If you want to ensure no overlap, you need to take advantage of some knowledge of how many rows/columns could be there.  e.g.: if months are columns, there can only be 12, etc.  If you have no known limit, then you are stuck and probably want to put the formulas somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot tables will expand down and to the right and will not care if there is any other data already in the cells. You may want to re-arrange your sheet to have formulas to the left and above any pivot table. That way, there is no risk of the pivot overwriting your formulas.